# Appcelerator Studio is very slow when scroll

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

- Appcelerator Studio, build: 4.7.1.201609100950
- macOS Sierra 10.12
- iMac (Retina 4K, 21.5-inch, Late 2015)
- Java 8
- Node.js 4.4.7
- npm 2.15.8
- Titanium CLI 5.0.9

I've tried (many times) to reinstall the editor, but without solving the problem. The editor is really really slow when scroll (after macOS Sierra update). It's impossible to use it without going crazy. I use Appcelerator Studio for many years and i have never had these problems.

There are other external components that could upgrade / reinstall? (Java.. etc etc)

Thanks

### Update

In addition to the slowdown, the editor does not properly recognize the file format.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had this slow down issue with appcelerator Studio as well (some of my colleagues swear by using Atom editor)... this happens with Appcelerator when you have one `.js` file that is huge (thousands of lines).

Ideally, split your js file into seperate commonJS files and coll them into the original js file with `require('filejs')`

Comment: No the problem isn't this. I have file (in another workstation) with 5-6 thousands lines of code, and there is no problem. And in this workstation (where there is the problem) the file is maximum 800 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

- I also had this problem for almost 1 month and I went completely crazy one day due to Studio slow-ness.
- I tried complete fresh installation of Appc & all of its components 2-3 times, but no luck.
- Then on one day, it was not working even like previous day, so I decided to completely format my MacintoshHD and re-install the macOS Sierra because I noticed that some other normal apps like Skype & Email were also started working slowly. So I got the idea that it's related to macOS Sierra update.

### ***Very Important Note (take system backup first)***

- Before installing OS, I took backup in external hard-drive and then I ran the First Aid (Disk Utility Tool) on MacintoshHD and found that there were some corruptions in it, so I fixed them but then something really crazy & out of this world happened with my system - **[Kernel Panic](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200553)** and my system did not start-up for 3 hours of hectic try.
- So the last solution was to format the Macintosh HD & install the OS again. The best way to do this is to make a bootable pen-drive having macOS Sierra in it and then install using it.
- Another way (if you have very good speed LAN) is to connect your system to Apple server and let it install latest OS from online. But it will download the whole OS & other required files (of at least **5GB** size).

There are many online tutorials on how to install macOS Sierra again after such creepy issues.

**FYI: I did re-installation of macOS Sierra last week & now everything is working like it is supposed to work on a Mac machine (just buttery smooth.).**